# Add file path parameter?

Tags: c++, winapi, parameters, filepath

How do I add the file path parameter under void pf? (I am new to C++)

As you can probably see, I am looking at forcing the cache of a certain file into the physical memory.

Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

void pf(const char* name) {

HANDLE file = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0,   OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if(file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { printf("couldn't open %s\n", name); return; };

unsigned int len  = GetFileSize(file, 0);

HANDLE mapping  = CreateFileMapping(file, 0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, 0);
if(mapping == 0) { printf("couldn't map %s\n", name); return; }

const char* data = (const char*) MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

if(data)
{
    printf("prefetching %s... ", name);

    // need volatile or need to use result - compiler will otherwise optimize out whole loop
    volatile unsigned int touch = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i += 4096)
        touch += data[i];
}
else
    printf("couldn't create view of %s\n", name);

UnmapViewOfFile(data);
CloseHandle(mapping);
CloseHandle(file);
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
if(argc >= 2) for(int i = 1; argv[i]; ++i) pf(argv[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest creating a new string that contains the file path and file name.

Comment: Can you give me an example and where to put it? as I said, I am brand new to C++ and this isnt even my code

Comment: The new string with file path would replace the filename string.  My understanding is that Windows API will accept full path names wherever a filename is required.

Comment: I just did that and it gave me a whole bunch of errors, let me just make sure I know what you are talking about. replace "name" with the file path of the file, correct?

Comment: What errors are you actually getting?  Please update your question to show the latest code you are using, the error messages you are getting and point out which lines of code they are referring to, and show how you are passing filenames to the program's input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very poorly worded, apparently because you know almost nothing about C++. This will give you a way to get started. Replace the main function with this:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    pf("C:\\SomeDir\\SomeFile.ext");
    return 0;
}
```

Then get a book and start learning how strings and functions work.